Kitchen faucet noise when running the water. Single handle
My kitchen faucet makes a high pitched noise the whole time the water is running. I live in a condo and my neighbors just had plumbing done. What could it be and how do I fix it?

Did your faucet not make noise before the neighbors plumbing work?  If so it could be some debris in the supply valves for your sink. This is assuming you and the neighbor share a common supply.

No noise before. We share the same boiler
